# inverse of a binomial matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, inverse

I have a matrix $A$ ($n \times n$) defined as follows:

$$A = \{ 0 \text{ if } i<j,\ \mathrm{Binom}(x=i, \mathrm{size}=j, \mathrm{prob})\text{ if } j \ge i\}$$

This is an upper triangular matrix, and I want to solve a system $Ax =b$ -- thus in a sense invert $A$.

I was wondering if a general inverse exists for this problem.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance..

Comment: So what you mean is that the $(i,j)$ entry is $\dbinom i j$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy \choose(j,i) prob^{i} *(1-prob)^{j-i}

Comment: You're using computer code instead of mathematical notation.  You can write $\dbinom j i p^i (1-p)^{j-i}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $q=1-p$ and $r = \frac pq$. Then
$$
A_{ij} = \begin{cases}{j\choose i} r^i q^j, & i\le j,\\0 & i>j.\end{cases}
$$
Therefore $A = \mathrm{diag}(r,r^2,\ldots,r^n)\ B\,\ \mathrm{diag}(q,q^2,\ldots,q^n)$ where
$$
B_{ij} = \begin{cases}{j\choose i}, & i\le j,\\0 & i>j.\end{cases}
$$
The matrix $B$ is intimately related to the definition of [Pascal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix). The entries of $C=B^{-1}$ are known to take the following form:
$$
C_{ij} = \begin{cases}{j\choose i} (-1)^{i+j}, & i\le j,\\0 & i>j.\end{cases}
$$
Hence the entries of the $M=A^{-1}$ are given by
$$
M_{ij} = \begin{cases}{j\choose i} (-1)^{i+j} q^{-i}r^{-j}, & i\le j,\\0 & i>j.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I just figured that out myself as well. Still, I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is a lower triangular matrix. Anyway, append it with an identity matrix and start eliminating from bottom to top (top to bottom). See [Gauss-Jordan elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination).

Comment: it is actually upper-triangular the way I defined it. I know how to solve the problem with elimination and backsubstition. The issue is when I do so, some of the x variables exceed double max-min limits thus can not be computed. For that reason, I am investigating whether a nice form of inv(A) exists

Comment: @Roark In your definition, both of inequalities are of $j \ge i$ form. Is it a typo?

Comment: No, it's not. The diagonal entries are then  prob^{i}