# What is this matrix of binomial distributions?

Tags: matrices, convolution, binomial-distribution

I have come across the following type of $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix:

$$C^n = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
 \beta^n(0) & 0   & \dots & 0  \\
 \beta^n(1) & \beta^{n-1}(0) & \dots & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
 \beta^n(n) & \beta^{n-1}(n-1)& \dots & \beta^0(0) \\
 \end{array} \right)$$

where $\beta^n(k) = {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}, k = 0,1,\dots, n$ is the vector of binomial distribution probabilities, and we define $\beta^0(0) = 1$. For example, for $n=3$ we have the matrix

$$ C^3 = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
 (1-p)^3  & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
 3 p(1-p)^2 & (1-p)^2  & 0  &0 \\
 3 p^2(1-p) & 2 p(1-p) & 1-p  & 0 \\
 p^3   & p^2  & p  & 1 \\
 \end{array} \right) $$

This matrix seems to have some interesting properties: it is clearly invertible; the lower right $n\times n$ submatrix of $C^n$ is $C^{n-1}$; and it appears that these matrices commute with convolution of probabilities, in the sense that

$$  C^{m+n} (x \otimes y) = (C^m x) \otimes (C^n y)$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ are discrete probability distribution vectors and $x \otimes y$ is the usual convolution operation.

Is anyone familiar with this kind of matrix? I would be grateful for any suggestions for literature/information. Have been searching for most of the day, but I'm probably not using the right keywords ... I am aware of the related Pascal matrices, but this seems a bit different.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235708/inverse-of-a-binomial-matrix

Comment: @TomChen  Yes, I saw that question, but it doesn't contain much on the properties of the matrix.  The factorization mentioned in one answer is useful though.

Comment: This is an example of a [left stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), with nonnegative entries whose column sums are $1$.  More can be said about this particular example, which is as you've noticed lower triangular and invertible.  Are you aware of / interested in the Markov chain associated with such matrices?

Comment: @hardmath  Interesting!  Yes, it would be great to get some information on related Markov chains, and other properties. If you could write up an answer and point me to some good references I would accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's invert the rows/columns of your matrix and adopt the following notation

$$
{\bf P}_{\,h} (p) = \left\| {\,P_{\,n,\,m} (p)\;\left| {\;0 \le n,m \le h} \right.\;} \right\|\;:\;P_{\,n,\,m} (p)
   = \binom{n}{m}p^{\,n - m} \left( {1 - p} \right)^{\,m} 
$$
which is
$$
{\bf P}_{\,h} (p) = \left\| {\matrix{
   {\left( \matrix{
  0 \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)p^{\,0} \left( {1 - p} \right)^{\,0}  = 1} & 0 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   p & {\left( {1 - p} \right)} & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   {\left( \matrix{
  2 \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)p^{\,2} } & {\left( \matrix{
  2 \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)p\left( {1 - p} \right)} & {\left( \matrix{
  2 \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)\left( {1 - p} \right)^{\,2} } &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \cr 
   {\left( \matrix{
  h \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)p^{\,h} } & {\left( \matrix{
  h \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)p^{\,h - 1} \left( {1 - p} \right)} & {\left( \matrix{
  h \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)p^{\,h - 2} \left( {1 - p} \right)^{\,2} } &  \cdots  & {\left( \matrix{
  h \cr 
  h \cr}  \right)\left( {1 - p} \right)^{\,h} }  \cr 
 } } \right\|
$$

We make this change in order to work with the "standard" Pascal Matrix 
$$
{\bf B}_{\,h}  = \left\| {\;B_{\,n,\,m}  = \binom{n}{m}\;\left| {\;0 \le n,m \le h} \right.\;} \right\|
$$
since we can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf P}_{\,h} (p) = \left\| {\,\binom{n}{m}p^{\,n - m} \left( {1 - p} \right)^{\,m} \;} \right\|\;
 = \left( {p^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} \left( {\left( {{{1 - p} \over p}} \right)^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)  \cr 
 &  = \left( {p^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)\left( {p^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}}
   = \left( {p^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} \left( {p^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {\bf B}_{\,h} ^{\,{\bf p}} \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right) = \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} ^{\,{\bf p}/{\bf q}}  =  \cdots  \cr} 
$$
where by
$$
\left( {f(n) \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)
$$
I indicate the diagonal matrix having the diagonal non null elements equal to $f(n)$.

Your matrix will then correspond to
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf C}_{\,h} (p) = \left\| {\;C_{\,n,\,m} (p) = \binom{h-m}{h-n}p^{\,n - m} \left( {1 - p} \right)^{\,h - n} \;} \right\| =   \cr 
  &  = {\bf J}_{\,h} \left( {\left( {1 - p} \right)^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf J}_{\,h} \left( {p^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf J}_{\,h} \,\overline {{\bf B}_{\,h} }
 \,{\bf J}_{\,h} \left( {p^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}}   \cr 
  &  = {\bf J}_{\,h} \,\overline {{\bf P}_{\,h} (p)} \,{\bf J}_{\,h}  \cr} 
$$
where the overbar indicates the transpose, and $\bf J$ the [exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix).

There are many properties that can be derived concerning the matrices $\bf P , \; \bf C$.

The first is that both are stochastic, as already noted
$$
{\bf u}_{\,h}  = \left\| {\,\matrix{   1  \cr    1  \cr     \vdots   \cr    1  \cr  } \,} \right\|
 = {\bf P}_{\,h} (p)\;{\bf u}_{\,h} \quad \overline {{\bf u}_{\,h} }  = \overline {{\bf u}_{\,h} } \;{\bf C}_{\,h} (p)
$$

The second is that, indicating as usual $q=1-p$, we clearly have
$$
charpoly\left( {{\bf P}_{\,h} (p)} \right) = charpoly\left( {{\bf C}_{\,h} (p)} \right) = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^h {\left( {x - q^{\,k} } \right)} 
$$
and the eigenvalues and the determinant are easily deducible.

Then since it is
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf P}_{\,h} (p)\,{\bf B}_{\,h}  = \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} ^{\,{\bf p}/{\bf q}} \,{\bf B}_{\,h}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} ^{\,\left( {{\bf p} + {\bf q}} \right)/{\bf q}}  = \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} ^{\,{\bf 1}/{\bf q}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)\left( {\left( {{1 \over q}} \right)^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} 
\left( {\left( {{1 \over q}} \right)^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {\bf B}_{\,h} \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right) \cr} 
$$
it comes out that the eigenvectors of $\bf P$ are given by the Pascal matrix $\bf B$
and that $\bf P$ diagonalize as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & {\bf P}_{\,h} (p)\, = {\bf B}_{\,h} \left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf B}_{\,h} ^{\, - \,{\bf 1}}   \cr 
  & {\bf C}_{\,h} (p) = {\bf J}_{\,h} \,\overline {{\bf P}_{\,h} (p)} \,{\bf J}_{\,h}
  = \left( {{\bf J}_{\,h} \overline {{\bf B}_{\,h} } ^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} } \right)\,\left( {q^{\,n}  \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right)\,\left( {{\bf J}_{\,h} \overline {{\bf B}_{\,h} } ^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} } \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}}  \cr} 
 }$$

From here it is easy to deduce the powers of $\bf P ,\; \bf C$, as well the functions developable into series.

Therefrom also follows the interesting, and expected, property:
$$
{\bf P}_{\,h} (1 - a)\;{\bf P}_{\,h} (1 - b) = {\bf P}_{\,h} \left( {1 - ab} \right)
$$
and same for $\bf C$, 
which suggests that we have better exchange $p$ and $q$ in the definition of $\bf P$.

Finally, looking at $\bf P$ as a transition matrix, it is apparent that if we define the single-step matrix $\bf Q$ as
$$
{\bf Q}_{\,h} (p) = \left\| {\;\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0 &  \ldots   \cr 
   p & {1 - p} & 0 &  \ddots   \cr 
   0 & p & {1 - p} &  \ddots   \cr 
    \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \ddots  &  \ddots   \cr 
 } \;} \right\|
$$
whose meaning is obvious , then the $k$-th row of $\bf P$ is the $k-th$ row of ${\bf Q}^{\,{\bf k}}$, i.e.
$$
{\bf P}_{\,h} (p) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,h} {\left( {\left[ {n = k} \right] \circ {\bf I}_{\,h} } \right){\bf Q}_{\,h} ^{\,{\bf k}} (p)} 
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), and
which is the same as saying that
$$
{1 \over {\left( {h + 1} \right)}}\left\| {\;1,1, \cdots ,1\;} \right\|\;{\bf P}_{\,h} (p) = {1 \over {\left( {h + 1} \right)}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,h} {\left\| {\;\left[ {0 = k} \right],\left[ {1 = k} \right], \cdots ,\left[ {h = k} \right]\;} \right\|{\bf Q}_{\,h} ^{\,{\bf k}} (p)} 
$$
the meaning of which is also obvious.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Do you know of any papers/books/source that deal with the matrix $P_h$ ?

Comment: @Roland: sorry to say that I have never seen this interesting matrix before.

Comment: @Roland: thanks for the appreciation. I added something concerning the interpretation as a Markov matrix. It's an interesting subject, thus please let me know if I can give more contribution or if find a reference or some important developments.